# Getting the exact timestamp from oracle database using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Editing the whole question .

In my oracle database table, the value of date is `23-07-23 12:00:00.000000000 AM`. The datatype is `TimeStamp(6)`

When I am trying to read this value using below code, I am getting `2020-07-23 00:00:00.0`.

How do I read the exact value? Finally I need to convert this to epoch time.

I am using below code for doing all this which is not giving me the correct answer.

```
Timestamp date = rs.getTimestamp(3);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);             
obj.setFlightDate(dateFormat.parse(formattedDate).getTime());
```

I am getting epoch time as **1595442600000**, whereas I should be getting **1595462400000**

[image]

Comment: 12:00 AM and 00:00 **are the same time**.

Comment: I know they are same time. But how do I achieve my expected epoch time?? What conversion should I do ?

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` is in the default JVM time zone (unless you use `getTimestamp(int, Calendar)`). Given the difference, it looks like your JVM has default time zone India Standard Time.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel . It seems that was the issue. Now its working fine.